# 5 kg hard honey in hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

Can I carry raw/hard (not the liquid one) honey in hand luggage when travelling from Lithuania (Vilna) to Stockholm with Airbaltics?

Comment: I would not, honey is mostly not hard enough not to be classed as liquid. In case of doubt they will just ban you from taking it on the plane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe. It depends on airport (I don't know Vilna) and on security staff. Often they allow it, but it is officially forbidden. See e.g. https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions:

> Liquids include: (...)
>   liquid or semi-liquid foods, for example soup, jam, honey and syrups

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on the daily mood of whoever is screening your hand luggage, but honey can be considered a paste and therefore prohibited in hand luggage.